# Question has been deleted even it was not down voted though less visited?

Tags: discussion, support

I understand if question has received many down votes it does not fit for **Serverfault** and it gets deleted. I am not sure if I am asking wrong question here but one of my question has been deleted and it did neither received down vote so far and nor even up vote too :). Though it failed to attract users to try and answer.

But what I asked was real problem which I encountered. I am just curios to know what exactly is the reason for deleting it. If it is something my fault I would be excited to know and will be more attentive while asking questions, though so far my journey with serverfault is amazing.

Hope I would get satisfactory answer as I always get :)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From this post: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount ≤ the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has ≤1 comments

**TL;DR** "Tumbleweed" Questions get automatically deleted as of May 2011

Comment: Ohh...  I never seen that post thanks for your reply :) Interesting ...